# Angular JS Promise all sequential

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, angular2-services

I am trying to execute 3 web services with promises, and I need that once all of them are executed, if possible sequentially, I will return the information of the 3 services.
I have this.

this is my service

```
getServices(url: string): Promise < any > {
  return this.http.get(CoordinadoresService.BASEURL + url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => err);
}
```

this is my component

```
getOffices() {
  this.oficinas["coordinadores"] = [];
  let data = this.util.getLocalStorage("coordinadores");
  let promises = [];
  if (data != undefined) {
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data.coordinadores).length; i++) {
      let url = `getOficinas/${data.coordinadores[Object.keys(data.coordinadores)[i]].ip}/${Object.keys(data.coordinadores)[i]}`;
      promises.push(this.services.getServices(url).then(response => {
          response["coordinador"] = response.coordinador;
          this.oficinas["coordinadores"].push(response)
        },
        err => err));
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
      console.log('Both promises have resolved', data);
    });
  }
}
```

But here he is giving me back undefined. why?

```
Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
  console.log('Both promises have resolved', data);
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Using `HttpClient` or `Http` ?

Comment: You're unwrapping the `Promise` by calling `then` on it. So your Promises array won't really have any `Promise` as such.

Comment: SiddAjmera i use Http

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand very well. What would be the solution for it?

Comment: by "sequentially" do you mean the 3 promises need to be done one after the other?

Comment: ohhh thank you SiddAjmera, I already understood, I solved it. Thank you!

Comment: Jaromanda, yes indeed one after the other

Comment: no idea what you just said ... do you need the `3 web services` to all run at once (parallel), or one after the other (sequentially)

Comment: @JaromandaX, `.then` yields a promise value only if it's returning from inside of `then`'s on-success callback function.

Comment: I'm talking about a `value` in the success callback of `.then` and not about just a `Promise`

Comment: you said `your Promises array won't really have any Promise as such` - you probably meant `your Promises array won't really have any VALUE as such` :p sorry for your confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your implementation.

1. First, if you use `HttpClient` you won't have to `map` and then call `json` on the response.
2. You didn't return from the `then` of `this.services.getServices(url)`. Hence no response in `Promise.all`

Following is the fix.

---

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
....
getServices(url: string): Promise < any > {
  return this.http.get(CoordinadoresService.BASEURL + url)
    .toPromise();
}

getOffices() {
  this.oficinas["coordinadores"] = [];
  let data = this.util.getLocalStorage("coordinadores");
  let promises = [];

  if (data) {

    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data.coordinadores).length; i++) {
      let url = `getOficinas/${data.coordinadores[Object.keys(data.coordinadores)[i]].ip}/${Object.keys(data.coordinadores)[i]}`;
      promises.push(this.getDataFromAPI(url));
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
      console.log('Both promises have resolved', data);
    });
  }
}

private getDataFromAPI(url) {
  return this.services.getServices(url)
    .then(
      response => {
        response["coordinador"] = response.coordinador;
        this.oficinas["coordinadores"].push(response)
        return response;
      },
      err => err
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting undefined's in your console.log is this code here

```
  promises.push(this.services.getServices(url)
 .then(response => {
      response["coordinador"] = response.coordinador;
      this.oficinas["coordinadores"].push(response);
      // nothing returned
  }, err => err));
```

As there is nothing returned (where noted), the Promise pushed into Promises will resolve to `undefined`

simply add a `return response`

note: `response["coordinador"] = response.coordinador;` is redundant, it's like saying `a = a` - so I wont be repeating it in code below

also `this.oficinas["coordinadores"]` is `this.oficinas.coordinadores` - so will be using the latter

```
  promises.push(this.services.getServices(url)
 .then(response => {
      this.oficinas.coordinadores.push(response);
      // something returned
      return response;
  }, err => err));
```

As to the other part of your question ... that you want to do this "sequentially"

If you can use `async`/`await` - that would make it very simple to change

```
async getOffices() { // add async keyword
    this.oficinas.coordinadores. = [];
    let data = this.util.getLocalStorage("coordinadores");
    let results = []; // no longer dealing directly with promises, so lets rename this
    if (data != undefined) {
        for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data.coordinadores).length; i++) {
            let url = `getOficinas/${data.coordinadores[Object.keys(data.coordinadores)[i]].ip}/${Object.keys(data.coordinadores)[i]}`;
            // await the promise
            let result = await this.services.getServices(url).then(response => {
                this.oficinas.coordinadores.push(response);
                return response;
            }, err => err);
            // push the result
            results.push(result);
        }
        // output the result
        console.log('Both promises have resolved', results);
    }
}
```

and - because

```
let url = `getOficinas/${data.coordinadores[Object.keys(data.coordinadores)[i]].ip}/${Object.keys(data.coordinadores)[i]}`;
```

just looks plain messy, let me suggest an alternative

```
async getOffices() {
    this.oficinas.coordinadores. = [];
    let data = this.util.getLocalStorage("coordinadores");
    let results = [];
    if (data != undefined) {
        for (let [key, {ip}] of Object.entries(data.coordinadores)) {
            const url = `getOficinas/${ip}/${key}`;
            let result = await this.services.getServices(url).then(response => {
                this.oficinas.coordinadores.push(response);
                return response;
            }, err => err);
            results.push(result);
        }
        console.log('Both promises have resolved', results);
    }
}
```